# jQuery-ui: Draggable working, but not resizeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make this div both draggable and resizable, however, the resizable function isn't working no matter what I try, but draggable works fine. The div is used to load a user's flash cards so they can view them in a video chat. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
    <title>Insert title here</title> 

    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {               

            $("#flash-card-div").hide(); 

            $("#flash-card-bttn").button(); 
            $("#draw-tool-bttn").button(); 
            $("#document-view-bttn").button(); 

            $("#flash-card-bttn").click(function(event) { 
                $("#flash-card-div").show(); 
                $("#flash-card-div").load("/toolbarcardviewer") 
            }); 

            $(function() { 
                $("#flash-card-div").resizable().draggable(); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
    <style> 

    ul { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        background-color: #f3f3f3; 
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7; 
        width = 100%; 
    } 
    li { 
        float: left; 
    } 

    #flash-card-div { 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 300px; 
        padding: 0.5em; 
    } 

</style>
<link type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 



<body> 

    <div id="toolbar"> 
        <ul id="tools"> 
            <li> 
                <button id="flash-card-bttn">Flash Cards</button> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
                <button id="draw-tool-bttn">Draw Tool</button> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
                <button id="document-view-bttn">Documents</button> 
            </li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 

    <div id="flash-card-div" class="ui-widget-content"> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

How do I make both of these functions work on this page? Did I do something wrong with linking the stylesheet or something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First, you do not need to call `$(function(){})` inside a `$(document).ready()` statement. Use one, or the other, not both. Second, since both draggable and resizable use `click` events, it's often helpsul to create a draggable handle to ensure the click event is not confused about which action to perform.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue. It's not clear what version of jQuery is being used, I am assuming v1.12.4. I tested with v3.3.1 and it seems to work properly.

I do see you are using a Custom jQuery UI download, so I would make sure it include the Resize widget.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#flash-card-div").hide();

  $("#flash-card-bttn").button();
  $("#draw-tool-bttn").button();
  $("#document-view-bttn").button();

  $("#flash-card-bttn").click(function(event) {
    $("#flash-card-div").show();
    $("#flash-card-div").load("/toolbarcardviewer")
  });

  $("#flash-card-div").resizable().draggable();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  width=100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

#flash-card-div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar">
  <ul id="tools">
    <li>
      <button id="flash-card-bttn">Flash Cards</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button id="draw-tool-bttn">Draw Tool</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button id="document-view-bttn">Documents</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="flash-card-div" class="ui-widget-content">
</div>
```

I click the button. The Flash Card appears. I can drag it. I can resize it.

If you're still having an issue, check your console for errors. Comment with more details if you find out more.

Hope that helps.